# nodejs middleware is skipped when called externally

Tags: node.js, express

I'm relatively new to Express and Node but this seems like a VERY basic demand and I am struggling to understand how it could be happening. Any help in solving the problem or identifying how I'd troubleshoot it would be VERY appreciated.

## Problem

```
var 
    express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    logger = require('morgan'),
    express = require('express'),
    app = express();

app.get('/heartbeat', function(req,res) {
    res.status(200).json(req.header('host'));
});

// my simple middleware component
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('made it');
    next();
});
// standard middleware components
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 

// Start listener
app.listen(4400);
```

This simple program does output my "made it" console message but yet when I wrap all the code (minus the variable definitions) in a function called start:

```
var 
    express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    logger = require('morgan'),
    express = require('express'),
    app = express();

var start = function(config) { ... }
exports.start = start;
```

and then call start from a separate module I find that the *logging* and *bodyParser* modules seem to execute but my middleware component is ignored. I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure why.

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 issues with your code:

1. You must call app.use() before calling app.get(...) Otherwise, none of the middlewares are called.
2. In your custom middleware, you need to call next() or next(error) so that the request is moved to the next middleware. Otherwise, your server hangs forever.

If you post your whole code after separating module, I can help you find more issues :)

Comment: This answers your question, also as you continue to use this framework look more into the router functionality present from express 4. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @Hoan, my actual code is hard to pull out succinctly so attempted to shortcut it here. I did actually have the next() call in my real code. Oops. As for the app.use() sequencing with app.get(), it appears to make no difference in my simple test. Are you sure about this? I can certainly play it safe and have the API endpoints follow the **use** middleware declarations.

Comment: I have tried the sequence reversal in the real code and it definitely works the same way regardless of sequence. I think this makes sense because the .get(), .post(), etc. methods are just event hooks and they aren't executed until after the service starts listening. Whereas the .use() calls are ways to inject steps into the event flow but I believe they would always precede the execution of the API endpoint. This is just me pontificating though, it would make sense that way but not sure it's true. That said, my tests do indicate to be true.

Comment: p.s. I added the next() call into my code above so this doesn't get in the way of the interpretation of the problem ... thanks for pointing this out.